# System of equations with left curly bracket

Tags: equations

For a system of equations, I would like to have a notation with a left curly bracket. Usually, I am using

```
\begin{equation}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll} 
f(x)=&x^2+\ldots\\
g(x)=&x^3+\ldots\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
```

But this makes a strange empty space between the "=" and the right-hand sides which i do not like since.

Is there a way to improve this easily?

Comment: You should consider the package `systeme`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @F.Pantigny This seems to be nice. However, if I have, for example, a left hand side as $z_k'$ it is not displayed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest you (a) employ an `aligned` environment instead of an `array` enviroment and (b) change both instances of `=&` to `&=`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' env.
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
  f(x) &= x^2+\ldots\\
  g(x) &= x^3+\ldots
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with a system of equations I usually prefer to use the "cases" environment.
[image: result example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

 \begin{equation}
  \begin{cases} 
    f(x) = x^2+\ldots\\
    g(x) = x^3+\ldots
  \end{cases}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This adds unwanted horizontal spaces at the right.